# How does Nuget Manager in Visual Studio store the internal chain of dependencies?

Tags: c#, data-structures, nuget, nuget-package

Does anyone know how does nuget manager stores the dependencies internally and which data structures are being used?

Example: application A might need to install some components say component C to work. Now C can further have few more dependencies and there might be some other components who are dependent on C. So how we can achieve this?

I am assuming we have to use Trees or Graphs. Graphs might be more suitable.

I tried searching for internal implementation guide about nuget manager or any such solution but I couldn't find any. There are plenty of blogs which talks about how we can use Nuget.

Please guide me.

Comment: When built, check `obj\project.assets.json`